# MVC 4 Ajax is not updating the PartialView within the page

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm doing a site using MVC 4. It's a site that list musics and the user can create a playlist (like a cart shopping).

I have for every music this action link that should be executed in Ajax:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Adicionar à Playlist","AddPlaylist", new { id = item.MusicaID }, new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId="playlist", InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace})
```

The action method from the controller returns a PartialView (the cart of playlist) and only that should update but instead of getting the whole page with that part updated I get a partial view and nothing more on the page.

This is the part where I render the PartialView:

```
<section id="playlist">
     @Html.Partial("_PlaylistPartial")
</section>
```

Shouldn't this work like I have?

Comment: Perhaps this solution is relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626225/mvc-4-ajax-is-not-updating-the-partialview-within-the-page

Comment: You put a link to my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a stupid thing.

First my include of jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js didn't work like I have:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So I put like this:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

And still wasn't working, because I also need to include the JQuery files:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.1.7.2.min.js")
```

This way it works :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have included

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in your view

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party but I just had a similar problem.  The solution was to add this line to _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, install `Microsoft.JQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax` from NuGet Manager and later include `~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive` in `BundleConfig` after including `jquery-{version}.js`; which will look something similar to this:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*));
```